# Not change current time in CompletableFuture.supplyAsync

Tags: java, completable-future

Here snippet (java 8)

```
LOGGER.info("==== MAIN: before_supplyAsync(), lastTimeSecLocal = {}, timeWindowSec = {}",
                                lastTimeSecLocal, timeWindowSec);
CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    long durationSecLocal = 0L;
    while (durationSecLocal < timeWindowSec) {
        long currentTimeSecLocal = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        durationSecLocal = currentTimeSecLocal - lastTimeSecLocal;
        LOGGER.info(
                    "\n\t\t>>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = {}, lastTimeSecLocal = {}, durationSecLocal = {}",
        currentTimeSecLocal, lastTimeSecLocal, durationSecLocal);
    }
        return true;
}); // end supplyAsync
```

And here logs:

```
2022-04-15 11:59:41.179 INFO  [MyClass:http-nio-172.19.5.163-8091-exec-9] ==== MAIN: before_supplyAsync(), lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, timeWindowSec = 15
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
2022-04-15 11:59:41.183 INFO  [MyClass:ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] 
                >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650013181, durationSecLocal = 0
```

Why **currentTimeSecLocal** not changed?

Comment: You're in a tight loop., which can apparently execute many times within the granularity of currentTimeMillis (which is probably ~10mS).  10mS is at least several tens of millions of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

currentTimeSecLocal should change every second, and it does

i runned this code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        long lastTimeSecLocal = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        long timeWindowSec = 10;

        log.info("==== MAIN: before_supplyAsync(), lastTimeSecLocal = {}, timeWindowSec = {}",
                lastTimeSecLocal, timeWindowSec);
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            long durationSecLocal = 0L;
            while (durationSecLocal < timeWindowSec) {
                long currentTimeSecLocal = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                durationSecLocal = currentTimeSecLocal - lastTimeSecLocal;
                log.info(
                        "\n\t\t>>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = {}, lastTimeSecLocal = {}, durationSecLocal = {}",
                        currentTimeSecLocal, lastTimeSecLocal, durationSecLocal);
            }
            return true;
        });
        
        completableFuture.get();
    }
```

and the log is:

```
[cut]
11:16:37.999 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014197, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 9
11:16:37.999 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014197, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 9
11:16:37.999 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014197, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 9
11:16:37.999 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014197, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 9
11:16:37.999 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014197, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 9
11:16:37.999 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014197, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 9
11:16:37.999 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014197, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 9
11:16:37.999 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014197, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 9
11:16:38.000 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO it.caensys.radbase.configuration.SecurityConfiguration - 
        >>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = 1650014198, lastTimeSecLocal = 1650014188, durationSecLocal = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This help (I don't understand why)

```
    LOGGER.info("==== MAIN: before_supplyAsync(), lastTimeSecLocal = {}, timeWindowSec = {}",
                                    lastTimeSecLocal, timeWindowSec);
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        long durationSecLocal = 0L;
        while (durationSecLocal < timeWindowSec) {
            long currentTimeSecLocal = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            durationSecLocal = currentTimeSecLocal - lastTimeSecLocal;
            LOGGER.info(
                        "\n\t\t>>>>>> supplyAsync: currentTimeSecLocal = {}, lastTimeSecLocal = {}, durationSecLocal = {}",
            currentTimeSecLocal, lastTimeSecLocal, durationSecLocal);
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(timeWindowSec * 100L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
    }
        return true;
}); // end supplyAsync
```